# Redistribute OSPFv3 static route to RIPng

Tags: cisco, router, ipv6, ospf, rip

I have a IPv6 static route on a Cisco 2600 that is being redistributed to other Routers in the same OSPFv3 area.  One of the routers (not the one with the static route) is also a participant in a RIPng group.  The OSPF routes are set to redistribute connected routes to RIPng, but the static route is not included in the redistribution.  The border router that is connected to both areas has the static route as type OE2.  Is there a command that I'm missing?

EDIT : I've created a diagram that shows a (simplified) topology of what I'm working with. We have a 6to4 tunnel between R1 and R5 (to traverse an IPv4 section of our network). Unfortunately, this link is treated as NBMA, thus static routes are required to establish the link between these two routers. The static route is defined at R1 (with redistribute statc on), visible through OSPFv3 on R2, but not being redistributed on R3 (even though all other learned routes on R2 ARE being redistributed).
[image]

Comment: Oh, just to clarify, I already have the RIPng configured to redistribute connected and it is successfully redistributing all learned OSPv3 routes to RIPng, except for the static route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using "redistribute static" on the router carrying the static route in question ?

EDIT : If the route is not propagating from the "bridge" router, you must do "redistribute rip subnets" in your OSPFv3 configuration.

Comment: Yes, the router that has the static route already has 'redistribute static' configured.  The other router, that bridges between the OSPFv3 and RIPng areas shows the static route as type OE2 when I run 'show ipv6 route', but it doesn't redistribute the route, even though all the other learned routes are being passed to RIPng.

Comment: Editer my answer to reflect your comment. A simple drawing would really help :-)

Comment: Can you post your configuration for R2 and R3 (edit your question) ? Have you added redistribute ospf <pid> in your RIP configuration ?

Comment: Yes, I did as you suggested.  After working on it last night, we discovered that a metric was not assiged to the redistributed static route.  After that, it started showing up!  Thanks for your help!